# how to call a presentModalView from a subView?

Tags: iphone, ipad

i'm working in ipad application,i have a viewController A which have many subviews viewcontroller  b,c,d,e,f... when i want to select a cell from one of viewcontroller to have a prsent modal view "full screen" it's not working ,how can i fix that

Comment: can you post some of your code..that will be helpful while answering

Comment: Just call `presentModalViewController` from the vc A.

Comment: @Mat i cant call from vc A because the methode of selecting is in vc B like this:

Comment: i can't call from VC A because i need to implement the didselect of uitableview from the VC B

Comment: Ok, but if i understand correctly your VCs are in the VC A, so the superview of each controller is the VC A, so you can pass the values to the controller of the superview A and then call presentModalViewController.

Comment: yes that what i do it ,finally it's work thx.i have another problem that the modalView didn't rotate with the diffrent orientation even i put it YES in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you have added all the viewcontroller  as a subview you don't need to present it

you just try

```
[self.view bringsubviewtofront:a.view];
```

hope this help ,

**EDIT**

```
  use following local notification  calling methods  to solve your problem,

  //place in class  from which you want to perform action
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
  selector:@selector(openLarge:)name:@"openLarge" object:nil];


  //place in class where you want to perform action
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"openLarge" 
  object:nil userInfo:nameDict];
```

regards,

Comment: I cant call from vc A because the methode of seleting is in vc B like this: